# Prevent css override from content loaded into a div

Tags: html, css

I developed a simple webmail client that connect to an account and download the emails to a postgres db. The problem is when i retrieve that content (HTML) into a div, when the email has css attributes, it overrides my css of entire page.

is there any workaround to prevent this?

*ps.: i'm putting the html code directly in div, some like this:*

```html
<div id="html-container">
    My html loaded from DB

</div>
```

Edit 1:

I forgot to mention that i'm using twitter-bootstrap on entire page.

Edit 2:

an example of e-mail downloaded and loaded on div :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
   <head>
      <title>Com quem eu devo falar?</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         v:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; }
         body {
         max-width:600px; 
         margin:auto;
         }
         td {
         cellpadding:0px; 
         border-spacing:0px;
         }
         tr {
         cellpadding:0px; 
         border-spacing:0px;
         }
         table {
         border-spacing:0!important; 
         border:none;
         }
         .containerbox {
         width:100%;
         max-width:600px!important;
         font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
         }
         #aweber_rem {
         margin: 0 auto;
         }
         center > div {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         }
         /*-----HEADER-----*/
         .headers {
         color:#ffffff;
         padding: 10px;
         height:330px;
         }
         .headers .headline {
         font-size:28px;
         color:#ffffff;
         font-weight: lighter;
         }
         .headers .paragraph {
         font-size:14px;
         color:#ffffff;
         line-height:150%
         }
         .headers a {
         color: #ffffff;
         }
         /*-----MAIN-----*/
         .main {
         font-size:14px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         padding: 10px;
         }
         .main .headline {
         font-size:24px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         }
         .main .paragraph {
         font-size:14px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         line-height:150%;
         } 
         .main a {
         color:#672833;
         }
         /*-----ARTICLES-----*/
         .article {
         font-size:14px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         padding-top:10px;
         padding-bottom:15px;
         }
         .article .headline {
         font-size:20px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         padding-bottom:5px!important;
         }
         .article .paragraph {
         font-size:14px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         line-height:150%;
         }
         .article .permalink {
         text-align: right;
         color:#672833;
         }
         .article td{
         padding:0px;
         }
         .article1 img{
         padding:10px 10px 0px 0px;
         }
         .article1 .paragraph{
         padding-top:5px;
         }
         .article3 img{
         padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;
         }
         .article3 .paragraph{
         padding-top:5px;
         }
         /*-----FOOTER-----*/
         .footers {
         font-size:14px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         padding:10px;
         }
         .footers .headline {
         font-size:20px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         }
         .footers .paragraph {
         font-size:12px;
         color:#4C4C4C;
         line-height:150%;
         } 
         .footers a {
         color:#672833;
         }
         /*-----MEDIA QUERIES-----*/
         /* Removes unwanted borders around hyperlinked images */
         a img {
         border:0;
         outline:none;
         text-decoration:none;
         }
         /* Smaller Mobile Devices */
         @media only screen and (min-width:10px) and (max-width: 400px) {
         .containerbox {
         max-width:300px!important; 
         margin:0 auto!important; 
         clear:both!important;
         }
         .sidebar2 td {
         display:block!important; 
         width:100%!important;
         }
         .main td {
         display:block!important; 
         width:100%!important;
         }
         table {
         width:100%;
         }
         .headline {
         font-size:20px;
         }
         .paragraph {
         font-size:16px;
         }
         img {
         height:auto!important; 
         max-height:300px; 
         max-width:100%;
         }
         .share img {
         width:20px!important;
         height:auto!important;
         display:inline-block;
         }
         }
         /* Larger Mobile Devices */
         @media only screen and (min-width:401px) and (max-width: 500px) {
         .containerbox {
         max-width:100%!important;
         margin:auto;
         clear:both!important;
         display: block;
         }
         table {
         width:100%;
         }
         .sidebar2 td {
         display:block!important; 
         width:100%!important;
         }
         .main td {
         display:block!important; 
         width:100%!important;
         }
         .headline {
         font-size:20px;
         }
         .paragraph {
         font-size:16px;
         }
         img {
         height:auto!important;
         max-height:300px;
         max-width:100%;
         }
         .share img {
         width:20px!important;
         height:auto!important;
         display:inline-block;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <center>
         <div align="center">
            <div class="containerbox" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, &quot;Helvetica Neue Light&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, sans-serif;">
               <center>
                  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                  &nbsp;
                  &nbsp;
                  &nbsp;
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px !important; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;">
                  <!--<![endif]-->
                  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="" width="600" style="background-color:;">
                     <![endif]--><!--Header-->
                     <tbody>
                        <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                           <td style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                              <table align="center" cellpadding="“5”" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#262626" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none; background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                       <td class="headers" background="https://www.aweber.com/images/email-templates/big-sale/red/red-header-img.png" style="text-align: left; border-spacing: 0px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px; height: 330px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                                          <div class="region">
                                             <div aw-contents="1">
                                                <table class="row" style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;">
                                                   <tbody>
                                                      <tr aw-contents="1" style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                         <td aw-attributes="width, valign" class="container" aw-contents="1" width="auto" valign="bottom" style="width: auto; border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                            <div class="definition-parent">
                                                               <span>
                                                                  <table align="center" width="100%" class="floated-none" style="float: none; text-align: center;
                                                                     border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;">
                                                                     <tbody>
                                                                        <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                           <td style="padding: 0px 0px 12px; border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                              <a class="aw-image-link" href="http://clicks.aweber.com/y/ct/?l=OUro1&m=3Xk0aqxqKa2iwPe&b=aetSWlAcBZYgxYi4YNkk4g" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                                                              <img align="center" class="model" border="0" aw-attributes="src,alt,width,height" style="margin: auto; width: 600px; height: 360px; border-width: 0px; border-style: none; outline-width: medium; outline-style: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/Mzc4NTM4/optimized/e0e1f0f6631a4eec813abade96420a7b.png" alt="Outsourcing de Impressão" width="600" height="360">
                                                                              </a>
                                                                           </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                     </tbody>
                                                                  </table>
                                                               </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--End Header--><!--Body-->
                        <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                           <td style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                              <table align="center" cellpadding="“5”" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  ="" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                       <td class="main" style="text-align: left; border-spacing: 0px; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(76, 76, 76); padding: 10px;">
                                          <div class="region">
                                             <div aw-contents="1">
                                                <table class="row" style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;">
                                                   <tbody>
                                                      <tr aw-contents="1" style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                         <td aw-attributes="width, valign" class="container" aw-contents="1" width="auto" valign="top" style="width: auto; border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                            <div class="definition-parent">
                                                               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="headline-element" width="100%"
                                                                  style="border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                     <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                        <td class="headline" style="padding: 10px; border-spacing: 0px; font-size: 24px; color: rgb(76, 76, 76);">
                                                                           <div aw-variable="value">
                                                                              <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:18px;"><span style="color:#696969;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms;"><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">OUTSOURCING/LOCAÇÃO DE IMPRESSORA</span></span></span></span></div>
                                                                           </div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                               </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="definition-parent">
                                                               <div class="paragraph" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(76, 76, 76); line-height: 150%;">
                                                                  <div aw-variable="value">
                                                                     <div><span style="font-size:20px">&nbsp;</span></div>
                                                                     <div>
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class=" cke_show_border" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;">
                                                                           <tbody>
                                                                              <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                                 <td style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                                    <div>
                                                                                       <div
                                                                                          style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:24px">Empresas&nbsp;<strong>inteligentes</strong>&nbsp;antecipam seus</span></div>
                                                                                       <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:24px">planejamentos para&nbsp;<u>reduzir seus custos</u>, e SIM&nbsp; podemos&nbsp;ajudar!</span></div>
                                                                                       <div style="text-align: center;"><br></div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                           </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                     <div>
                                                                        <div><span style="font-size:14px">Olá,&nbsp;</span></div>
                                                                        <div><span style="font-size:14px"></span><br></div>
                                                                        <div>
                                                                           <span
                                                                              style="font-size:14px"></span>
                                                                           <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width: 763px; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;" class=" cke_show_border">
                                                                              <tbody>
                                                                                 <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                                    <td style="width: 763px; border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                                       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width: 763px; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;" class=" cke_show_border">
                                                                                          <tbody>
                                                                                             <tr style="border-spacing:
                                                                                                0px;">
                                                                                                <td style="width: 763px; height: 490px; border-spacing: 0px;">
                                                                                                   <div><em>Olá, bom dia!</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Estou escrevendo com o intuito de encontrar a pessoa apropriada </em><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>para&nbsp;falar&nbsp;sobre&nbsp;Outsourcing de Impressão,</em><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em> visando reduzir os custos de impressão de sua empresa e compras de Toner de Impressora.</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>.</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>A&nbsp;<strong>Asia Print&nbsp;</strong>, uma empresa com 16 anos de mercado,
                                                                                                      fornece soluções de impressão, </em><br>
                                                                                                   </div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>além de suprimentos cartuchos e toners, tanto original como compatíveis. </em><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Trabalhamos com as principais marcas do mercado Brother, </em><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>HP, Lexmark, Epson, Samsung, dentro outras.</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Garantimos o melhor PREÇO! Nos Toners compatíveis e originais!</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Reduza seu custo de impressão, procure nossos
                                                                                                      consultores.</em>
                                                                                                   </div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Caso você seja a pessoa a&nbsp;quem&nbsp;se destina este e-mail, </em><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>para quando podemos agendar uma ligação?&nbsp;</em><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Se não for você, me indicaria a pessoa de contato?</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Agradeço a sua atenção!</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Um abraço,</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><span style="background-color:
                                                                                                      initial;"><i>Elisângela</i></span><em>&nbsp;Velasco</em></div>
                                                                                                   <div><br></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>E-mail:&nbsp;</em><a data-cke-saved-href="mailto:vendas@asiaprint.com.br" href="mailto:vendas@asiaprint.com.br" target="_blank" class="validating" style="color: rgb(103, 40, 51);"><em>vendas@asiaprint.com.br</em></a></div>
                                                                                                   <div><em>Telefone:&nbsp;<a data-cke-saved-href="tel:(11)%204117-9969" href="tel:(11)%204117-9969" value="+551141179969" target="_blank" class="validating" style="color: rgb(103, 40, 51);">(11)
                                                                                                      4117-9969</a></em>
                                                                                                   </div>


[cutted by stack character limit]
```

Comment: Maybe using `!important` in every selector in your site css?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap in entire page.

Comment: thanks for reply @sweaver2112. Is there a way to do that without remove style of email content loaded?

Comment: @Hackerman I wouldn't suggest using !important on every selector. That is not recommended.

Comment: I know it's a last resort....but with so little info, that was like my best guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [web components](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#css-and-shadow-dom) to encapsulate all the CSS.

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <style>
.test{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
}
</style>
  My html loaded from DB
  <span class="test">test</span>
  
</template>

<div id="html-container"></div>

<span class="test">test</span>

<script>
  var tmpl = document.querySelector('template');
  var host = document.querySelector('#html-container');
  var root = host.createShadowRoot();
  root.appendChild(document.importNode(tmpl.content, true));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove the current inline styles from the e-mails you have two options:

1. Learn to live with it - not a good choice because you might end with white text on white background.
2. Use !important in every possible selector as mentioned. The main ones are **color** and **background** to ensure that everyone can read it's content. Is it elegant? Best practice? No. But this is the only way to gain relevance against inline styles.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Looks like I don't have reputation to comment on the main question. But this can be considered an answer. Care to explain why not?

Comment: And also look at @Alex answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Hackerman. Also, Alex's answer is really good. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest and the most cross-browser solution is to display the contents of the email in an iFrame. Note, you can generate an iFrame with a certain content using javascript, as such:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var emailDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
emailDoc.open();
emailDoc.write(
    '<head>' +
        '<style>/* styles go here */</style>' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body><!-- content goes here ---></body>'
);
emailDoc.close();
```

The styles inside an iFrame will not leak into the styles inside the main document and vice versa.